# AVG of Cells Next to Cells used in Another Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to asking questions here so I hope I get this correct. I am helping my dad with a spreadsheet and I'm having issues with figuring out how to do one formula. Dont know if it can be done with a formula or if it has to be done with macros.

This is a scoring sheet with multiple matches. For each match there is a total score and the cell next to the score is an X count (number of bulleyes). In the same row (column K) I calculate the top 6 total scores and average them:

> =AVERAGE(LARGE((N15,Q15,T15,W15,Z15,AC15,AF15,AI15,AL15,AO15,AR15,AU15,AX15,BA15,BD15,BG15,BJ15),{1,2,3,4,5,6}))

Now I need to take the AVG of the X counts that are next to the total scores that are used in the formula above and put solution in column L.

For example, if the cells that are used for AVG score in that row are:

> N15,Q15,T15,W15,Z15,AC15

then the cells that would need to be used for the X count AVG would be:

> O15,R15,U15,X15,AA15,AD15

This result would be put into `L15`

Please help. If any clarification is needed just let me know.

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

Comment: If you drag the formula from K15 to L15, that will happen automatically.

Comment: @Gserg is right but I think the count of bull's-eye is not directly proportional to the score so you will get the average of the top 6 count which is not the respective count of the top 6 scores? Am I getting this right?

Comment: Correct, the AVG of the X count is in relation to the values that are used in K15. So it wont be the same formula. I need to use the cells next to the cells that are used in the top 6 avg of the scores.

Comment: Could you put a header in the cells above the bullseye totals and then do a SUMIF() / COUNTIF() on rows 14:15? Also post a sample of how the data is laid out and what you want the result to look like. It will be easier to answer that way.

Comment: Not sure how to post this cropped image from excel

Comment: Post it in a free image hosting site (e.g. http://imgur.com) then post the link in comment and we will take it from there.

Comment: http://imgur.com/q7NTmxL

Comment: Each row will have a different result from the next. In the image it shows that I set up conditional formatting to highlight the top 6 scores in red. The problem is that my dad then has to manually go and select the cells next to the red cells to get that average and have that result be in column L. Just trying to automate this process because there are over 150 people and too many errors can happen by doing it manually every time.

Comment: Can you post the sample excel file if possible that will help greatly. also Try to show the header by freezing top row.

Comment: The link to the excel file is: m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429974642640.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(O15:BM15,
--(MOD(COLUMN(N15:BL15)-COLUMN($N15),3)=0),
--(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6>=
   LARGE(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6,6))
   )/6
```

How does it work?

`SUMPRODUCT` has 3 parameters - first is the array to sum, next 2 parameters return an array of `0` and `1` to choose only interesting elements of the first array.

- `MOD(COLUMN(N15:BL15)-COLUMN($N15),3)=0)`

This part is included to avoid listing every single cell. If the score is in every third column of the input range, we can calculate column number relative to first column, and function MOD(column,3) returns: `{1,0,0,1,0,0...}`. So only every third column of input array will be included in sum.

- `(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6>=
     LARGE(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6,6)`

This part is to decide which 6 of the scores should be included in the final sum. The trickiest part is to decide what to do with ties. My approach is to take:

- if two scores are the same, take the one with higher number of bulleyes
- if it is still tied, take the one from first columns

This means that instead of `N15` value we calculate:

```
N15+O15/10^3+COLUMN(N15)/10^6
```

With your sample data it evaluates to: `566.017014`. First three decimal places is the number of bulleyes, next 3 is column number.

You can use the same formula to calculate average of top 6 scores by changing the first parameter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N15:BL15,
--(MOD(COLUMN(N15:BL15)-COLUMN($N15),3)=0),
--(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6>=
   LARGE(N15:BL15+O15:BM15/10^3+COLUMN(N15:BL15)/10^6,6))
   )/6
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect!!! Also, much appreciated for a little explaination that was given. Thanks again.

Comment: Too much logic here I'd say :). If I can UV you more that once, I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this not so elegant solution:

> =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(N15:BK15,MATCH(LARGE((N15,Q15,T15,W15,Z15,AC15,AF15,AI15,AL15,AO15,AR15,AU15,AX15,BA15,BD15,BG15,BJ15),{1,2,3,4,5,6}),N15:BK15,0)+1))/6

Entered as *array formula* by <kbd>Ctr+Shift+Enter</kbd> in Cell L15:M15 (2 cells) which should look like this:

> {=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(N15:BK15,MATCH(LARGE((N15,Q15,T15,W15,Z15,AC15,AF15,AI15,AL15,AO15,AR15,AU15,AX15,BA15,BD15,BG15,BJ15),{1,2,3,4,5,6}),N15:BK15,0)+1))/6}

with added braces.

The number `6` is the equates to the number of top scores you want returned.
Now, why 2 cells (L15:M15). I cannot make `SUMPRODUCT` evaluate the resulting array from the `INDEX` so we have to enter it at 2 cells. I don't think that would be a problem since in your screen shot, Column M is not used.

**Note:** If the range evaluated have less than 6 items, it will error out. Also good point by user3964075. It may or may not be able to deal with ties.

Comment: I think it might give wrong result when there are ties.

Comment: @user3964075 Good point since `MATCH` always returns the first match.

Comment: Yeah, Im not sure Im fully understanding the L15:M15 2 cell deal. When I put the formula in L15 it gives a result of 5 and it should be 18.5. I have a sample spreadsheet that I can send if that would make things easier. Whats the best way to post sample excel file?

Comment: @DrNosh please provide a link to a sample excel file.

Comment: @DrNosh You need to select the two cells. Then copy the formula and put it in formula bar. Then hit the CTE. That will give you the correct average if there are no ties in the top 6. Btw, you can upload your file in any free file sharing site and then just post the link in your question.